# Laravel assigning classes to blade files dynamically fails

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to assign classes if a route match a certain pattern.

suppose i have these `urls` as below:

```
user-management/users
user-management/roles
user-management/role?user=andy
user-management/permissions
```

Now i would like to add active class to a link. So i have tried:

```
<li class="{{ (Request::path() == 'user-management/*')  ? 'dropdown active ' : 'dropdown' }}">
```

But the above fails to add active class. Trying with:

```
<li class="{{ (Request::path() == 'user-management/users')  ? 'dropdown active ' : 'dropdown' }}">
```

Which works when i visit `/user-management/users`

How can i make the other one work with all the `user-management` link `urls`

What else could be wrong?

Am using laravel 5.5 and my routes in `web.php` are

```
Route::group(["middleware"=>'auth', 'prefix'=>'user-management'], function (){
Route::get("users", "UsersController@ShowUsers")->name("user-management.users");
  Route::get("roles", "UsersController@ShowRoles")->name("user-management.roles");
 .....others follow
```

});

Comment: You can do it by: `class="{{ Request::is('user-management/*') ? 'dropdown active' : 'dropdown' '' }}"`

Comment: Thanks this now works

Comment: Ok, Please accept and upvote my answer if this helps you!

Comment: surely done thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it for all `user-management` URL. Like:

```
<li class="{{ Request::is('user-management/*') ? 'dropdown active' : 'dropdown' '' }}>
```

Hope this works for you!